# how to keep the paragraph background from disappearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, background, fade

There is a list. Each list item has a click event. When the click event is fired(they click on the list item), that information is displayed in the html paragraph. Problem: Each time a new line is clicked, the whole paragraph disappears before the new information is displayed. How can I stop this from happening?

```js
var symbols = { 
  Horn: 'A horn in Bible prophecy is a king or kingdom Power and Strength: Daniel 7:24; 8:5, 21, 22; Zechariah 1:18, 19; Revelation 17:12', 
  Beast: 'Kingdom, government, political power: Daniel 7:23',
  Bear: 'Destructive Power / Medo Persia: Proverbs 28:15; 2 Kings 2:23-24; Daniel 7:5',
  Dragon: 'Satan or his agency: Isaiah 27:1; 30:6; Psalms 74:13,14; Revelation 12:7,9; Ezekiel 29:3; Jeremiah 51:34',
  Black: 'Moral darkness, sin, apostasy: Exodus 10:21-23; Jeremiah 4:20-28; 8:21; Acts 26:18; John 12:35; Joel 2:1-10',
  Wine: 'blood/covenant/doctrines: Luke 5:37, Isaiah 5:1-7',
  Eyes: 'Spiritual Discernment: Matthew 13:10-17, 1 John 2:11',
  Blood: 'Life: Leviticus 17:11; Deuteronomy 12:23',
  Angel: 'Messenger: Daniel 8:16; 9:21; Luke 1:19,26; Hebrews 1:14',
  Babylon: 'Religious apostasy/confusion: Genesis 10:8-10; 11:6-9; Revelation 18:2-3; 17:1-5',
  Crowns: 'Kingship, victory: 1 Chronicles 20:2; 2 Kings 11:12; Ezekiel 21:26,27; James 1:12; 2 Timothy 4:7,8; 1 Corinthians 9:25',
  Bow: 'Success in battle against evil: Psalms 7:11,12; Psalms 45:4,5',
  Clothing: 'Character: Isaiah 64:6, Isaiah 59:6',
  Cup: 'Meted out suffering and judgments: Psalms 11:6; Isaiah 51:12,22-23; Jeremiah 25:12-17; 49:12',
  Day: 'Literal year: Ezekiel 4:6; Numbers 14:34',
  Door: 'Opportunity/Probation: 2 Corinthians 2:12; Revelation 3:20; Luke 12:24, 25',
  Dove: ' Holy Spirit: Mark 1:10',
  Eagle: 'Speed, Power, vision, vengeance, protection: Deut 28:49; Habakkuk 1:6-8; Revelation 12:1-4',
  EatingOfTheBook: 'Assimilating the message: Ezekiel 3:1-3; Jeremiah 15:16',
  Egypt: 'Symbol of atheism: Exodus 5:2',
  EyeSalve:'Holy Spirit to help us see truth, discernment to understand word, antidote for spiritual blindness: Ephesians 1:12-19; Psalms 119:18; I John 2: 20,27; John 16:7-13',
  FaithfulWitness: 'Christ: John 18:37; John 3:11; Revelation 1:5; 3:14; 19:11',
  FalseProphet: 'Apostate Protestantism: Revelation 16:13,14; 13:13,14; 19:20',
  Famine: 'Dearth of Truth: Amos 8:11',
  Feet: 'Your Walk / Direction: Genesis 19:2, Psalms 119:105',
  Forehead: 'Mind: Romans 7:25; Ezekiel 3:8,9',
  Fornication: 'Illicit connection between church and world: Ezekiel 16:15,26; Isaiah 23:17; James 4:4; Revelation 14:4',
  FourBeastsOfLivingCreatures: 'Heavenly beings with special responsibilities: Revelation 5:8-10; 4:6-9; 6:1-7; 14:3; 15:7; 19:4',
  FourCornersOfEarth: 'Four directions of compass: Jeremiah 49:36',
  Fire:  'Holy Spirit: Luke 3:16',
  FigTree: 'A Nation that should bear fruit: Luke 13:6-9',
  Field: 'World: Matthew 13:38, John 4:35',
  Fruit: 'Works / Actions: Galatians 5:22',
  Garments: 'Covering of righteousness: Genesis 35:2; Isaiah 61:10; 52:1; Zechariah 3:3-5; Romans 13:14',
  Gold: 'True riches of heaven, faith, scripture: Psalms 19:7-10; Galatians 5:6; James 2:5; Job 23:10; Isaiah 13:12',
  Goat: 'Greece: Daniel 8:21',
  Hand: 'Symbol of Deeds / Works / Actions: Ecclesiastes 9:10, Isaiah 59:6',
  Harvest: 'End of World: Matthew 13:39',
  Harlot: 'Apostate church/religion: Isaiah 1:21-27; Jeremiah 3:1-3; 6-9',
  Heads: 'Major powers/rulers/governments: Revelation 17:3, 9, 10; Daniel 7:6; 8:8,22',
  Healing: 'Salvation: Luke 5:23-24',
  HiddenManna: 'Christ: John 6:49,50,53; Matthew 13:44',
  Honey: 'happy life: Ezekiel 20:6, Deuteronomy 8:8-9',
  Horse: 'Strength and Power in Battle Special representatives/angel: Job 39:19, Psalms 147:10, Proverbs 21:31; Exodus 15:21; Isaiah 43:17; Jeremiah 8:6 Zechariah 1:8-10; 6:1-8',
  Image: 'A likeness: Exodus 20:4; Genesis 1:26; 5:3',
  Incense: 'Prayers of God’s people: Psalms 141:2; Revelation 5:8',
  Israel: 'True Followers of Christ: Romans 9:6-8; 2:28,29; Galatians 3:29',
  JarVessel: 'Person: Jeremiah 18:1-4, 2 Corinthians 4:7',
  Jezebel: 'Immorality, Idolatry, Apostasy: 1 Kings 21:25; 2 Kings 9:22',
  Jordan: 'death: Romans 6:4, Deuteronomy 4:22',
  KeyOfDavid: 'Power to open & close the sanctuary: Revelation 3:7-9; Isaiah 22:22',
  Keys: 'Control/jurisdiction: Isaiah22:22; Matthew 16:19',
  Lamb: 'Jesus/sacrifice: John 1:29; 1 Corinthians 5:7; Genesis 22:7,8',
  Lamp: 'Word of God: Psalms 119:105',
  LambsWife: 'New Jerusalem: Revelation 19:7-9; 21:2,9,10',
  Lion: 'Jesus/Powerful King i.e. Babylon: Rev. 5:4-9, Jer. 50:43-44, Dan. 7:4,17,23',
  Locusts: 'Destruction: Joel 1:4; Deuteronomy 28:38',
  Leopard: 'Greece: Daniel 7:6',
  LeprosySickness: 'Sin: Luke 5:23-24',
  LordsDay: 'The Sabbath: Isaiah 58:13; Matthew 12:8; Exodus 20:10',
  ManChild: 'Jesus: Psalms 2:7-9; Revelation 12:5',
  Mark: 'Sign/Seal/mark of approval or disapproval: Romans 4:11; Ezekiel 9:4; Revelation 13:17; 14:9-11; 7:2, 3',
  MeasuringRod: 'God’s Law God’s Word: James 2:10-12; Ecclesiastes 12:13,14 Isaiah 8:19,20; 2 Timothy 3:16,17',
  Merchants: 'Advocates of Babylon’s teachings: Isaiah 47:11-15;Nahum 3:16; Revelation 18:3,11,15,23',
  Moon: 'Permanence Moses’ system of types of sacrifices Psalms 89:35-37 Hebrews 10:1,11',
  MorningStar: 'Jesus: Revelation 22:16',
  Mountains: 'Political or religion-political powers: Isaiah 2:2, 3; Jeremiah 17:3; 31:23; 51:24, 25; Ezekiel 17:22, 23; Daniel 2:35, 44, 45',
  MysteryOfGod: 'The gospel: Ephesians 1:9,10, 3:9, 6:19; Colossians 1:26,27',
  NewJerusalem: 'The Holy city of Heaven: Revelation 3:12, 21:2',
  Oil: 'Holy Spirit: Zechariah 4:2-6; Revelation 4:5',
  OpenDoor: 'Unlimited Opportunity 1 Corinthians 16:9; Acts14:27; John 10:7-9 Hosea 2:15; Colossians 4:3',
  Purple: 'Royalty: Mark 15:17, Judges 8:26',
  Rainbow: 'Token of covenant keeping: Genesis 9:11-17',
  Ram: 'Medo Persia: Daniel 8:20',
  RedScarlet: 'Sin/corruption: Isaiah 1:18; Nahum 2:3; Revelation 17:1-4',
  Reapers: 'Angels: Matthew 13:39',
  Reins: 'Seat of will, affections: Psalms 7:9, 16:7, 26:2, 73:21; Proverbs 23:16; Jeremiah 17:10',
  Ring: 'Authority: Genesis 41:42-43, Esther 3:10-11',
  Rock: 'Jesus/truth: 1 Corinthians 10:4; Isaiah 8:13,14; Romans 9:33; Matthew 7:24',
  Seal: 'Sign or mark of approval or disapproval: Romans 4:11; Revelation 7:2, 3',
  Seed: 'Descendents / Jesus: Romans 9:8, Galatians 3:16',
  SecondDeath: 'Lake of fire: Revelation 21:8; 20:2',
  Serpent: 'Satan: Revelation 12:9; 20:2',
  SevenCandleSticks: '7 candlesticks in Holy Place of Sanctuary Seven Churches Exodus 25:31-40; Revelation 1:20',
  SevenHeads: 'Seven Political Powers: Revelation 17:9,10; Isaiah 2:2-4',
  SevenLamps: 'Jesus, Word of God: John 9:5, 1:9; Psalms 119:105; Revelation 4:5',
  Sickle: 'Symbol of Harvest-End of world: Matthew 13:39; Revelation 14:14',
  Silver: 'Pure Words & Understanding: Proverbs 2:4, 3:13-14, 10:20, 25:11, Psalms 12:6',
  Sodom: 'Moral degradations: Ezekiel 16:46-55; Jeremiah 23:14; Genesis 19:4-14',
  Stars: 'Angels/messengers: Revelation 1:16, 20; 12:4, 7-9; Job 38:7',
  Sun: 'Jesus/the gospel: Psalms 84:11; Malachi 4:2; Matthew 17:2; John 8:12; 9:5',
  Skin: 'Christs righteousness: Exodus 12:5, 1 Peter 1:19, Isaiah 1:4-6',
  Sword: 'Word of God Bloodshed, Destruction: Ephesians 6:17; Hebrews 4:12 Isaiah 3:25, 13:15; Acts 12:1,2; Jeremiah 48:2',
  TestimonyOfJesus: 'Holy Spirit/ gift of prophecy: Revelation 19:10; 22:9; 1 Corinthians 13:2',
  ThornsThornyGround: 'Ground Cares of this life: Mark 4:18-19',
  Tongue: 'Language / Speech: Exodus 4:10',
  Time: '360 Day (Literal Years): Daniel 4:16, 23, 25, 32; 7:25; Daniel 11:13 margin',
  Times: '720 Days (Literal Years): Daniel 7:25, Revelation 12:6,14, 13:5; 11:1,2',
  Trumpet: 'loud warning of Gods approach: Exodus 19:16-17, Joshua 6:4-5',
  Tree: 'Cross; People / Nation: Deut. 21:22-23, Psalms 92:12, 37:35',
  Torment: 'Test, prove by trial: 1 Corinthians 3:13; Hebrews 12:29; Isaiah 33:14',
  TwoEdgedSword: 'God’s word: Ephesians 6:17; Hebrews 4:12; Matthew 10:34',
  TwoWitnesses: 'Old and New Testaments: John 5:39, Zechariah 4:1-14; Psalms 119:130, 105; John 12:48',
  Vineyard: 'Church that should bear fruit: Luke 20:9-16',
  Waters: 'Inhabited Area-People/ Nations: Revelation 17:15',
  Water: 'Holy Spirit / Everlasting Life: John 7:39, 4:14, Rev. 22:17, Eph. 5:26',
  White: 'Purity: Revelation 12:9; 20:2',
  WhiteRobes: 'Victory/righteousness Revelation 19:8; 3:5; 7:14',
  Winds: 'Strife, Commotions, “winds of war” Jeremiah 25:31-33,49:36,37, 4:11-13; Zechariah 7:14',
  Wings: 'Speed / Protection / Deliverance: Deuteronomy 28:49, Matthew 23:37',
  WomanPure: 'True Church: Jeremiah 6:2; 2 Corinthians 11:2; Ephesians 5:23-27',
  WomanCorrupt: 'Apostate church: Ezk. 16:15-58; 23:2-21; Hos. 2:5; 3:1; Rev. 14:4',
  Wolf: 'Disguised Enemies that hunt in a time of darkness Matthew 7:15',
  Wormwood: 'Sorrow/bitterness: Jeremiah 9:15, 23:15; Lamentations 3:19',
  WrathOfGod: 'Seven Last Plagues: Revelation 15:1'
};

$('li').on('click', function(){
  var symb = $(this).html();
  if (Object.keys(symbols).indexOf(symb) > -1) {
   console.log(symbols[symb]);
    $('#symbolDef').html(symbols[symb]);
}  
  $('#symbolDef').fadeOut(0, function(){
    $('#symbolDef').fadeIn(2500);
  $('#symbolDef').html(symbols[symb]);
    $("#symbolDef").css("font-size", "125%");
  });
})
```

```css
body {
background-image:url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/8892/pexels-photo.jpg?w=1260&h=750&dpr=2&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb');
}

#carved{
  font-size:4em;
  text-align:center;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #8A0707; 
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1.5px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
  text-shadow:2px 2px 5px lightblue;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}


.main-list {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  background: black;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius:15px;
  border:1px solid #CBF1F1;
  box-shadow:-10px 10px 20px black;
  margin-top:30px;
}

.main-list h3 {
/*   margin: 0 auto; */
  text-shadow:-2px -2px 5px white;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px white;
  border-radius:10px;
}

h3{
  background-image:url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/164175/pexels-photo-164175.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&dpr=2&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb');
  font-weight:bold;
  width:200px;
  transition:2s;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #8A0707; 
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1.5px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
  padding-bottom:6px;
}

h3:hover{
  image:url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/235985/pexels-photo-235985.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&dpr=2&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb');
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #e60000; 
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
   text-shadow: 2px 3px 10px black;
  font-size:2.0em;
  text-shadow: -2px 3px 10px white;
}

ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  overflow:auto;
  box-shadow:10px 10px 25px black;
  border-radius:15px;
  background-image:url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/235985/pexels-photo-235985.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&dpr=2&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb');
 border:1px solid lightgrey;
}

li { 
  cursor: pointer; 
  margin-right:15px;
 background-image:url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/164175/pexels-photo-164175.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&dpr=2&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb');
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #8A0707; 
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1.5px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  border-radius:10px;
  margin-top:5px;
  transition-property: font-size;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  border-top:1px solid black;
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
  font-size:1.5em;
  text-shadow:-2px -2px 2px white;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px white;
}

li:hover{
  background-image:url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/164175/pexels-photo-164175.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&dpr=2&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb');
  margin-bottom:5px;
  margin-top:5px;
  font-size:2em;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #e60000; 
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1.5px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
  text-shadow:-2px -2px 2px white;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px white;
}

p{
  background-image:url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/164175/pexels-photo-164175.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&dpr=2&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb');
  height:100px;
  width:325px;
  overflow:auto;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:15px 0px 0px 15px;
  padding-left:20px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 150px white;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #8A0707; 
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
  font-size:1.5em;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 5px black;
  border:1px solid black;
}

p:hover{
  padding-left:20px;
  background-image:url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/164175/pexels-photo-164175.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&dpr=2&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb');
  border-radius:15px 0px 0px 15px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px white;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 150px white;
 }




.container{
  margin-top:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id = 'carved'>Bible Prophecy Decoder</h1>
<div id = 'skyDaddy' class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column main-list">
      <h3 class="w3-display-middletop" style='margin-left:20px;'>Symbol List</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Horn</li>
        <li>Beast</li>
        <li>Bear</li>
        <li>Dragon</li>
        <li>Black</li>
        <li>Wine</li>
        <li>Eyes</li>
        <li>Blood</li>
        <li>Angel</li>
        <li>Babylon</li>
        <li>Crowns</li>
        <li>Bow</li>
        <li>Clothing</li>
        <li>Cup</li>
        <li>Day</li>
        <li>Door</li>
        <li>Dove</li>
        <li>Eagle</li>
        <li>EatingOfTheBook</li>
        <li>Egypt</li>
        <li>EyeSalve</li>
        <li>FaithfulWitness</li>
        <li>FalseProphet</li>
        <li>Famine</li>
        <li>Feet</li>
        <li>Forehead</li>
        <li>Fornication</li>
        <li>FourBeastsOfLivingCreatures</li>
        <li>Fire</li>
        <li>FigTree</li>
        <li>Field</li>
        <li>Fruit</li>
        <li>Garments</li>
        <li>Gold</li>
        <li>Goat</li>
        <li>Hand</li>
        <li>Harvest</li>
        <li>Harlot</li>
        <li>Heads</li>
        <li>Healing</li>
        <li>HiddenManna</li>
        <li>Honey</li>
        <li>Horse</li>
        <li>Image</li>
        <li>Incense</li>
        <li>Israel</li>
        <li>JarVessel</li>
        <li>Jezebel</li>
        <li>Jordan</li>
        <li>KeyOfDavid</li>
        <li>Keys</li>
        <li>Lamb</li>
        <li>Lamp</li>
        <li>LambsWife</li>
        <li>Lion</li>
        <li>Locusts</li>
        <li>Leopard</li>
        <li>LeprosySickness</li>
        <li>LordsDay</li>
        <li>ManChild</li>
        <li>Mark</li>
        <li>MeasuringRod</li>
        <li>Merchants</li>
        <li>Moon</li>
        <li>MorningStar</li>
        <li>Mountains</li>
        <li>MysteryOfGod</li>
        <li>NewJerusalem</li>
        <li>Oil</li>
        <li>OpenDoor</li>
        <li>Purple</li>
        <li>Rainbow</li>
        <li>Ram</li>
        <li>RedScarlet</li>
        <li>Reapers</li>
        <li>Reins</li>
        <li>Ring</li>
        <li>Rock</li>
        <li>Seal</li>
        <li>Seed</li>
        <li>SecondDeath</li>
        <li>Serpent</li>
        <li>SevenCandleSticks</li>
        <li>SevenHeads</li>
        <li>SevenLamps</li>
        <li>Sickle</li>
        <li>Silver</li>
        <li>Sodom</li>
        <li>Stars</li>
        <li>Sun</li>
        <li>Skin</li>
        <li>Sword</li>
        <li>TestimonyOfJesus</li>
        <li>ThornsThornyGround</li>
        <li>Tounge</li>
        <li>Time</li>
        <li>Times</li>
        <li>Trumpet</li>
        <li>Tree</li>
        <li>Torment</li>
        <li>TwoEdgeSword</li>
        <li>TwoWitnesses</li>
        <li>Vineyard</li>
        <li>Waters</li>
        <li>White</li>
        <li>WhiteRobes</li>
        <li>Winds</li>
        <li>Wings</li>
        <li>WomanPure</li>
        <li>WomanCorrupt</li>
        <li>Wolf</li>
        <li>Wormwood</li>
        <li>WrathOfGod</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <p onclick = ' myFunction()' class='w3-center'><span  id='symbolDef'></span>Interpretation</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this happens because of this line of your code `$('#symbolDef').fadeIn(2500);`

the time to perform the animation is too long. When it starts to fade in, the next animation would be performed until the previous one is finished.

So, when a user select an item of the element and then quickly select another one before 2500 ms. the new paragraph keeps fading in and then it fades in again once it finishes.

I suggest to reduce the fade in time. Reduce it enough time to finish before the user would select another item of the list. let's say `$('#symbolDef').fadeIn(250);` would be enough

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't wanna animation?
It's hard to understand your message.
If you wanna to instantly switch context use:

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
  var symb = $(this).html();
  if (Object.keys(symbols).indexOf(symb) > -1) {
   console.log(symbols[symb]);
    $('#symbolDef').html(symbols[symb]);
}  
  $('#symbolDef').html(symbols[symb]);
  $("#symbolDef").css("font-size", "125%");
})
```

Comment: thanks for responding. The solution was to target the span instead of the paragraph. Everytime i clicked for a new definition of a different symbol, the whole paragraph would fade out then fade in with the new definition. I only wanted the text in the paragraph to fade out and in, so a span fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
    var symb = $(this).html();

    $('#symbolDef').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        if (Object.keys(symbols).indexOf(symb) > -1) {
            console.log(symbols[symb]);
            var div = $("<div id='symbolDef'>" + symbols[symb] + "</div>").hide();
            $(this).replaceWith(div);
            $('#symbolDef').css("font-size", "125%").fadeIn('slow');
        }
    });
})
```